# Modify variable based on @Input

Tags: angular

I have an array in a component which gets initialized during the Init. Based on @input value the array needs to be modified. During the onChanges the array seem to be empty. How can this be achieved?

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
@Input()
pickedStudents: Student[] = [];
studentSubscription: Subscription;
students: Student[] = [];
constructor(private studentService: StudentService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.studentSubscription = this.studentService.getStudents().subscribe(a => this.students = a);
}
ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.pickedStudents && this.pickedStudents.length) {
        //This is for instance. The problem is students seem to be empty here.
        this.students.splice(this.students.indexOf(this.pickedStudents[0]), 1);
    }
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.studentSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
}
```

Comment: no one know what happen if u dont show your code...

Comment: Is this a child component or where does this `pickedStudents` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a condition in the ngOnChanges as below

```
ngOnChanges(){
    if(this.arrayName && this.arrayName.length){
            your operation
    }
}
```